# Icon not visible in Lumino widget title

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am trying to add a Lumino widget to the 'right' panel of the Jupyter Lab UI. However, I am not able to set the icon in the title bar of the widget using font awesome icons. Here's my code:

```
class ExampleWidget extends Widget {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.id = 'myextension-widget'
        this.title.label = 'Sample'
        this.title.closable = true
        this.title.iconClass = 'face-smile'
        this.addClass('mypanel')
      }
    }
```

What am I missing here? Can someone please help?

Comment: More Jupyter-specific folks might see this at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/).

Comment: thank you @Wayne I posted my question in Discourse.

Comment: I should have mentioned to note when you cross-post in both locations so that everyone has access to all that is said. I'll add the link here. [Your post on Jupyter Discourse site](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/icon-not-visible-in-lumino-widget-title/14151?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- had the 'fa' class
- fix the font class name ('fa-smile-o' instead of 'face-smile')

This example works for me:

```
class ExampleWidget extends Widget {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.id = 'myextension-widget'
        this.title.label = 'Sample'
        this.title.closable = true
        this.title.iconClass = 'fa fa-smile'
        this.addClass('mypanel')
      }
    }
```